# How to preload lazy loaded modules in Nativescript

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I hope the title is quite self explanatory. Nativescript now supports AOT and lazy loading, but I am struggling to achieve preloading on top of the example at https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng. If you run the example provided, you will notice that 1s lag between switching pages (loading different modules).

Is this possible with Nativescript 2.5?

Comment: Here's you can get a example https://github.com/sis0k0/lazyNinjas

Comment: Yes, thank you, that example is showing lazy loading, but not preloading of lazy loaded routes :) I want to avoid that 1s lag, while the route is being loaded on request (i.e. preload it before the user taps on the new route).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, at least in NS 3.0. I asked this in nativescript forums:
https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/is-it-possible-to-preload-lazy-loaded-modules/1363

It's very easy, you just have to use directly the Angular Router feature:

 `NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES,
        {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules} // import { PreloadAllModules } from "@angular/router";
    )`

Comment: Ok, you should also see this issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/809